# Transform XSD's gYearMonth into Joda's YearMonth

Tags: jaxb, xsd, jodatime

I have an WSDL file referencing an XSD file with elements of the type `gYearMonth` in it. I cannot change it. I'd like to use JAXB to automatically generate classes with members of the type `YearMonth` of the Joda-time library.

I've seen the article [JAXB and Joda-Time: Dates and Times](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html) to be quite interesting, but I'm interested in performing this binding on the fly from the WSDL to Java rather than Java to WSDL.

I created my `XmlAdapter` (yeah, no wizardry in here):

```
import org.joda.time.YearMonth;
public class YearMonthAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String,YearMonth> {
  @Override public YearMonth unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    return new YearMonth(v);
  }
  @Override public String marshal(YearMonth v) throws Exception {
    return v.toString();
  }
}
```

But where and how do I register it in my `bindings.xml` so that I get `YearMonth` rather than `XMLGregorianCalendar` when the code is generated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a binding file like the following to hook in an `XmlAdapter` when generating a a Java model from XML Schema.

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="format.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='number']">
            <jxb:property>
                <jxb:baseType>
                    <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.Integer"
                        parseMethod="blog.xmladapter.bindings.NumberFormatter.parseInt"
                        printMethod="blog.xmladapter.bindings.NumberFormatter.printInt" />
                </jxb:baseType>
            </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

for more information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html

Comment: Thanks, it works. +1'd. But for the accepted answer, I'd like answers to two things (they are quite explicit in the original question): 1. I want to make all `gYearMonth` Joda's `YearMonth`, do I have to list all names? using `@type` doesn't seem to work. 2. I wrote my XmlAdapter with no static method. Can't JAXB reuse it rather than forcing me to make static versions of the methods and write the method names, typically, something like `<javaType name="org.joda.time.YearMonth" adapter="my.YearMonthAdapter">`? Extra kudos if this is adapted to a globalBindings rather than an on-XSD base.

Comment: Use `jaxb:globalBindings` to only having to define the binding single time. Use `xjc:javaType adapter="your.path.to"` to define the adapter itself, not the static parse and print methods.